# Grails Integration Test Controller can't be re-used?

Tags: grails, grails-controller, grails-2.2

In a grails integration test, I have code that resembles this:

```
def ctrlA = new MyController()
... make some request that returns 'ok' ...
assert ctrlA.response.json.status == 'ok'

def ctrlB = new MyController()
... make some request that returns 'error' ...
assert ctrlB.response.json.status == 'error' // fails; status still equals 'ok'
```

Problem: Even when `ctrlB` actually does return a json response that looks like `{ status: 'error' }`, I'm actually seeing `{ status: 'ok' }`, the value that was in `ctrlA.response.json`!! My logs in the controller indicate that 'error' is most definitely being returned.

Why is this?

Comment: Hi, Could you post your complete test class?  We cannot get any integration tests to work, we always get null responses.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't programmed in grails for quite a while now, and I no longer have access to that code. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah. Don't need the separate `ctrlA` and `ctrlB` at all. Just call `ctrl.response.reset()` in between.